# SQL - Select rows with distinct one column for each non-unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I've seen similar questions posted here before, but the twist on my question is that I can't partition via a unique ID.

Here's what my table Request_Data looks like:

```
ID  Request_ID  Location  Order_Code  Review_Status
=================================================
1   1           HQ         SXXXXF     Not Reviewed
2   1           Scranton   ASDFGH     Reviewed
3   1           Scranton   ABCDEF     Reviewed
4   1           Binghamton PSDFJG     Not Reviewed
5   2           Scranton   GGGGGG     Reviewed
6   2           Stamford   PRWERE     Not Reviewed
7   2           Scranton   UYUIFG     Reviewed
```

I want my query to return:

```
Request_ID  Location    Review_Status
==================================================
1           HQ          Not Reviewed
1           Scranton    Reviewed
1           Binghamton  Not Reviewed
2           Scranton    Reviewed
2           Stamford    Not Reviewed
```

Putting it into words, my table references a foreign key request id, which contains multiple order codes to be reviewed, which each have an area.  An area's order codes are all reviewed at once, so I only need one record returned per request id per area to get the review status for that area.

I know it's a weird design; I didn't set this up, but I have to work with it.  Thanks.

Comment: What if Scranton  has `Not Reviewed` in row with ID = 3?

Comment: That would never happen, areas are all reviewed at once for a request.

Comment: Then why don't you use a simple DISTINCT: `SELECT DISTINCT Request_ID, Location, Review_Status FROM Request_Data`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just want `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by request_id, location order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns the first record for each `request_id`/`location` pair.

Answer (score 1):

You need use rownumber()

for example :

```
SELECT
NEW_TBL.*
FROM
(SELECT
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY ID) AS ROWNUM
            ,TBL.*      
      FROM Request_Data TBL
  ) NEW_TBL
WHERE 
NEW_TBL.ROWNUM = 1
```